# Admob Native Ads with Realm DataBase

Tags: java, admob, realm

I am trying to show AdMob native ads in my RecyclerView, the problem is the NativeExpressAdView only accepts List, so is there any way I can convert RealmResults to List in

```
private void setUpAndLoadNativeExpressAds() {
    // Use a Runnable to ensure that the RecyclerView has been laid out before setting the
    // ad size for the Native Express ad. This allows us to set the Native Express ad's
    // width to match the full width of the RecyclerView.
    mRecyler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final float density = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            // Set the ad size and ad unit ID for each Native Express ad in the items list.

            //Here is the problem :
            for (int i = 0; i <= randomQuote.size(); i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {
                final NativeExpressAdView adView =
                        (NativeExpressAdView) randomQuote.get(i);
                AdSize adSize = new AdSize(
                        (int) (mRecyler.getWidth() / density),
                        NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_HEIGHT);
                adView.setAdSize(adSize);
                adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
            }

            // Load the first Native Express ad in the items list.
            loadNativeExpressAd(0);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Realm.copyFromRealm()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyFromRealm-java.lang.Iterable-).

Comment: Can you give me a sample code on what I should exactly do, please?

Comment: `RealmResults<Person> results = realm.where().findAll(); List<Person> persons = realm.copyFromRealm(results);`